# PayPal IPN Credit Card Numbers

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to set up an account with StreamingVideoProvider.co.uk and set up pay per view.  They ask to connect with my paypal's ipn.

Will they have access to our customers sensitive information such as credit card number or will paypal encode that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A credit card number will never be returned via IPN. Though depending on your account configuration, it *can* return a billing address or other PII data such as a first / last name, email address and shipping address.

Having said that; if they're asking you to specify your own IPN URL in their software, then no, they can't intercept it.
If they are providing an IPN URL on their domain, then yes, they can see the data I mentioned above.
You would need to ensure they handle this data in a secure manner.